# What's wrong with my variable assignment?

Tags: bash, unix, variable-assignment, fibonacci

I'm trying to code a fibonacci function that takes an input int as length of sequence. Here's my code:

```
function fib {
        local len=$1
        echo "len = $len"

        local arr=(0 1 1)

        if [[ $len -le 3 ]]
        then
                echo ${arr[@]:0:$len}
                let arr=${arr[@]:0:$len}
                echo $arr
        else
                while [[ ${#arr[*]} -lt $len ]]
                do
                        local sum=${arr[${#arr[*]}]}+${arr[${#arr[*]}-1]}
                        let arr+=$sum
                        echo "curren len = ${#arr[*]}"
                done
        fi

        echo "arr = $arr"
}
```

And here's what I get when I call the function:

```
 fib 2
len = 2
0 1
0
arr = 0
 fib 3
len = 3
0 1 1
0
arr = 0
```

Please ignore if it's efficient for now. Why is it i get the right sequence when simply echoing? But not when I `let arr=`?

Comment: Try echoing the computed sum and the appended arr inside the loop. Are they what you expected?

Comment: I think the append is supposed to be `arr+=($sum)` (without `let`). I'll leave debugging the sum to you,

Comment: Ah thanks! @teapot418 I forgot to use the array parenthesis!! But when do I need to use `let` then?

Comment: `let` is for evaluating arithmetic expressions. You don't really want that when just appending. Computing the sum should probably be one.

Comment: `let` does not really support array assignments. The variable which gets assigned to, needs to be a scalar.

Comment: Because you are not expanding the array, you are expanding its `[0]` element.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) suggests [Instead of `let expr`, prefer `(( expr ))`](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2219).

Comment: Don't try to do this in shell, it's not what shells are designed to do and so it'll be immensely slow, complicated, and hard to get right. Use one of the tools that shells are designed to sequence calls to instead (awk, perl, python, ruby, etc...).

Answer (score 3):

You need to read through the long and boring chapter on expansions in `man bash`, which shows how arrays are used. `"${array[@]}"` expands an array’s values as separate tokens. `"${!array[@]}"` expands an array’s indices (or keys) as separate tokens. Using `*` instead of `@` produces a single string, delimited by the first character from `$IFS`. Expanding an array variable as a scalar (`"$array"`) yields `"${array[0]}"`, which may or may not exist, because indexed arrays are sparse and may not contain a `[0]` element and associative arrays may or may not contain a `['0']` key. The snippet below also shows the nice “debugging” expansions provided by Bash. (Look for `@A`.)

```bash
generate_fibonacci_sequence() {
  local -i counter="$1"
  local -n _output_array="$2"  # declare -ai
  _output_array=()
  ((counter)) || return 0
  local -i a=0 b=1
  for ((;;)); do
    _output_array+=(a)
    ((--counter)) || return 0
    ((b += a))
    _output_array+=(b)
    ((--counter)) || return 0
    ((a += b))
  done
}

declare -ai sequence

for length in {0..20}; do
  generate_fibonacci_sequence "$length" 'sequence'
  printf '%s\n%s %s %s\n' "${length@A}" "${sequence[@]@A}"
  printf '['
  for i in "${!sequence[@]}"; do
    printf '(%d:%d)' "$i" "${sequence[i]}"
  done
  printf ']\n\n'
done
```

Beginning of the output:

```
length='0'
declare -ai sequence=()
[]

length='1'
declare -ai sequence=([0]="0")
[(0:0)]

length='2'
declare -ai sequence=([0]="0" [1]="1")
[(0:0)(1:1)]

length='3'
declare -ai sequence=([0]="0" [1]="1" [2]="1")
[(0:0)(1:1)(2:1)]

length='4'
declare -ai sequence=([0]="0" [1]="1" [2]="1" [3]="2")
[(0:0)(1:1)(2:1)(3:2)]

length='5'
declare -ai sequence=([0]="0" [1]="1" [2]="1" [3]="2" [4]="3")
[(0:0)(1:1)(2:1)(3:2)(4:3)]

length='6'
declare -ai sequence=([0]="0" [1]="1" [2]="1" [3]="2" [4]="3" [5]="5")
[(0:0)(1:1)(2:1)(3:2)(4:3)(5:5)]

length='7'
declare -ai sequence=([0]="0" [1]="1" [2]="1" [3]="2" [4]="3" [5]="5" [6]="8")
[(0:0)(1:1)(2:1)(3:2)(4:3)(5:5)(6:8)]

...
```

In any case, note that Bash uses signed 64-bit integers under the hood, with underflow / overflow behaviors that would be considered *undefined* in (e.g.) C++:

```
$ echo $((2**63))
-9223372036854775808
$ echo $((2**63 - 1))
9223372036854775807
```

With that said, it may be better to calculate large Fibonacci numbers in Python, which uses GNU MP under the hood. (Or use GNU MP directly.)